# How to fix Google colab import errors on statsmodels logsumexp and factorial

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, python-3.3

Am getting import errors in google collab Jupyter notebook on statsmodels packages such as logsumexp and factorial.

Please suggest.

```
from scipy.misc import logsumexp
from scipy.misc import factorial 
ImportError: cannot import name 'logsumexp'
ImportError: cannot import name 'factorial'
```

I have re-installed the scipy and sci-kit and restarted runtime of google collab jupyter notebook. However, import still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was looking for a similar problem in colabs and did the below:

```
! pip install --upgrade Cython
! pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

Got it from the below link: [This issue is solved temporarily](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5759#issuecomment-494086228)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on google colab. then i got same problem "can not import name :factorial".Actually it comes from `scipy` .

**For windows**

```
pip3 install --user scipy==1.2.0
```

**For Linux**

```
python3.6 -m pip install scipy==1.2 --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

change

> from scipy.misc import factorial

to

> from scipy.special import factorial

in a couple of places (everywhere, where you get an error message)
same with

> comb, logsumexp