# cannot import name 'Appender' from 'statsmodels.compat.pandas' in google colab error?

Tags: google-colaboratory, pmdarima

I am trying to import  `from  pmdarima.arima import auto_arima` and
`from  pmdarima.arima import ADFTest` but it giving me error `cannot import name 'Appender' from 'statsmodels.compat.pandas'`
I tried `!pip install pmdarima` in google colab but it is still giving me error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same and fixed it by downgrading scipy

> pip install pmdarima scipy==1.2 -Uqq

got it from [How to fix Google colab import errors on statsmodels logsumexp and factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253309/how-to-fix-google-colab-import-errors-on-statsmodels-logsumexp-and-factorial)

A restart of the runtime environment was needed after installation.